# "NP-complete" authentication systems

Tags: authentication

Are there any *symmetric* authentication systems based on the hardness of an NP-complete problem? I understand that it doesn't really matter, since NP-completeness is about the worst case, and in crypto we care about the average case, but I still feel it's somewhat interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the turtle block cipher with CMAC, maybe.

The [turtle block cipher](http://www.crypto.com/papers/turtle.pdf) claims a cipher design that is based on "an NP-Complete Subproblem".

Block ciphers can be used to produce authentication tags via algorithms such as [CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC).

I'm not sure if this combination necessarily qualifies the authentication as being based on an NP-Complete subproblem too.